# adjust width of inner / child elements

Tags: css

I have a parent DIV which may have 1,2 or 3 child elements. If the parent has only one element the child should have 100% width, if 2 then each element should have 50% of available width and in case of 3 elements each child should have 33.3333% of width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid tables and are fine with *flexbox* (which is supported by [all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)), your solution would be simply

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.container > * {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

with

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

(works fine for more elements as well).

```css
/* solution */
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.container > * {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* for demo */
.container {
  height: 30px;
}
.container > * {
  height: 100%;
}
.container > :first-of-type {
  background-color: red;
}
.container > :nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: green;
}
.container > :nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h3>one item</h3>
<div class="container">
  <div></div>  
</div>

<hr>

<h3>two items</h3>
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<hr>

<h3>three items</h3>
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: according to http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox you have to add a `-ms-` prefix but then yes. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ is a great resource for that.

Comment: actually, you have to use `-ms-flex-align: stretch` instead of `align-items: stretch`, if i read everything correctly. sadly (or luckily?) I have no IE near me...

Answer (score 2):

Use table layout

```css
.wrap{
border: 1px solid green;
min-height: 100px;
display: table;
width: 100%;
}
.wrap > div{
border: 1px solid red;
display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div class="box">div 1</div>
<div class="box">div 2</div>
<div class="box">div 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: But what if I have only one element within wrap element

Comment: Remove the other two divs, it will work fine - [https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/2tmaLb32/](https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/2tmaLb32/)